# Rich HTML field show same content for 2 different fields

Tags: master-page, page-layout, publishing-page, html, richhtmlfield

I want to use 2 richhtmlfield and 2 richImagefield in HTML in the same row in the same page layout to show 2 different images and captions. It didn't work for me. I tried to change ID but didn't work either. Can anybody help me with this.